# Are these two re-writes the same?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

How are the following different? Ignore the domain names.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The difference is "^"?

What I basically want to do is have my site as http://yourdomain.com and never have the www appear. For a start its shorter and its good for SEO as my site won't be judged as two sites. One with www and one without.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

The first says, redirect to the host `example.com` if the host is `www.example.com`.
The second says, redirect to `www.example.com` if the host is not `www.example.com`.

And even if you would rewrite the second to the following (having both rules redirecting to `example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So that it would redirect to `example.com` if the host is not `example.com`. The result might be the same if the host can only be `www.example.com` and `example.com`. But if it can have more values than that (e.g. `foobar.example.com`), the your first rule *would not* redirect while my *would* redirect.